# How to composer-require Magento2 develop branch?

Tags: magento2, composer

I am currently installing the Magento 2 modules via a

```
"require": {
    "magento/product-community-edition": "*"
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "http://packages.magento.com/"
    }
],
```

in my `composer.json` - but this gets only the latest beta releases.

I try changing the version from `"*"` to `"dev-develop"` but this version is not found.

Is there a way to composer-install the latest development branch of Magento 2?

*Edit*

I gave this one a try:

```
{   "minimum-stability": "dev",
      "require": {
          "magento/magento2ce": "dev-develop"
      },
      "repositories": [
          {
              "type": "vcs",
              "url": "https://github.com/magento/magento2.git"
          },
          {
              "type": "composer",
              "url": "http://packages.magento.com/"
          }
      ]
}
```

But I end up without an `app/` folder and it could not create `app/etc/vendor_path.php`. So I manually create `app/etc` before `composer.phar install`. `composer install` now succeeds but the `pub/` folder is missing... Might be the wrong approach.

Comment: Can you figure anything out based on [Composer's aliasing docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/aliases.md)? I did [ping Jordi](https://twitter.com/benmarks/status/652851556845531136), we'll see if he has anything to say.

Answer (score 4):

Currently Magento 2 does not have packages for developers branch, so you can not install it with the composer.

The reason for that, there is no mechanism in the compositor to say that the package in the development and it should not be cached. As result re deploy of packages will not has effects without cleanup of cache.

Comment: You are talking about `packages.magento.com`? Would there be a way via GitHub?

Comment: Yes, about `packages.magento.com`. You can not use composer to obtain magento from github, but can just checkout with git and use.

Comment: Sure, but then my project code would be mixed with Magento's code. What would it need to allow obtaining Magento from GitHub?

Comment: You can  make symlink of module/theme to magento instance to not mix code.